# Import Error with @react-three/fiber / @react-three/drei

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-fiber, drei

I'm trying to use some components from @react-three/drei and it gives me a ton of import errors. No matter what I try to use from @react-three/drei, I get these errors.
Example:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/three-stdlib/loaders/EXRLoader.js 1703:52-62
export 'RGBEFormat' (imported as 'RGBEFormat') was not found in 'three'
```

Another example:

```
export 'RGBEEncoding' (imported as 'RGBEEncoding') was not found in 'three'
```

These are the project's dependencies:

```
    "@react-three/drei": "^8.3.1",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^7.0.24",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "three": "^0.136.0",
    "three-stdlib": "^2.6.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
```

I appreciate the help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Three.js migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide) says "RGBEEncoding and RGBEFormat have been removed". from 136.
Try using 135 instead.

Comment: Thanks! I was going crazy over this issue for hours lol.